# Loader bug jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

gente estou com um problema em meu jquery
jQuery:

```
/Pre-Loader
     jQuery(window).load(function () {

         $('.site').hide(1);
         $('.id-sub').hide();
         $("#loading").fadeOut(2000,function(){
             $('.site').show("slow");
             $('#n2-ss-2-align').show(1);
             var currentPage = window.location.hash;//captura o link da pagina
             if (currentPage) {
                 $(currentPage).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');
                 $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(currentPage).offset().top });
             }
    });



     });
```

estou fazendo acima escondendo o `.site` porem se eu nao utilizar  `$('.site').hide(1);` o valor 1 e deixar sem valor o meu Slider não aparecer estou utilizando plugin `Smart Slider` porém se eu deixar com (1) ele mostra o conteúdo escondendo poderiam me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

OBS: ja utilizei tbm `.css("display", "none");` e nao funciona.

Comment: Cara sua pergunta está meio confusa, da pra vc dar uma revisada no texto?

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou clara, você carrega  o site e esconde ele, para fazer a animação com o preLoader é isto? O que é a classe **.site**, é o site inteiro?